# Python 3 application unexpectedly pauses, resumes on keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a pretty reource hungry Python 3 application (64 bit, Windows 7, run from Powershell) that constantly maxes one core when running, and also uses quite a bit of memory. Right now around 10 GiB.

It periodically prints output to console, but sometimes I notice that it just stops. The CPU utilization then also goes down from 12%-13% to 0%. This goes on until I press a key, such as spacebar in the console windows, when everything kicks back in.

What is going on here?

Comment: I had the same problem on macOS, turned out macOS was just putting itself to sleep after the display had turned off. Adjusting energy settings fixed this. Could it have to do with Windows' energy settings?

Comment: I wouldn't rule it out completely, but fwiw this happens with the screen still on.

Comment: Could it because there are some `input()` inside your application? I know it sounds stupid, but sometimes it really could happen...

Comment: No input(). There is some writing to file, though. It happens quite frequently. Could that be related, somehow?

Comment: It is possible to block your application but impossible to resume if you just press a key... Or could it because there are some `subprocess.call` which require an input? Or remote call?

Comment: I don't even know what subprocess.call is, so no, that's not being used. Nothing remote either. Just calculations and disk I/O (only O at this stage of the application's runtime).

Comment: Could it be related to this? https://serverfault.com/questions/204150/sometimes-powershell-stops-sending-output-until-i-press-enter-why

Comment: I think that's it @MarkDickinson! Thanks a lot.